# How can I get this VBA IF THEN Statement to work

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a multi-select ListBox for selecting "colours" and have copied the code into a second module and renaming as required, in order to create a second ListBox for "tags". There is also code in Worksheet SelectionChange that I am trying to amend in order to get both of them working.

This is the code for 1 ListBox

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, ColourArea(ActiveSheet)) Is Nothing Then 
        If Target.Column = 8 And Target.Offset(0, -6).Value = "Variable" Then
            CreateColourPopUp Target
        End If
    Else 
        DeleteAllPopUps Target
End Sub
```

And below is the code with my attempt at adding in the 2nd ListBox.
Everything I have tried alternates with "block if without end if" errors, to one of them working, to none. How can I fix this code?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, ColourArea(ActiveSheet)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Column = 7 And Target.OFFSET(0, -5).Value = "variable" Then
            CreateTagPopUp Target
        End If
        If Not Intersect(Target, TagArea(ActiveSheet)) Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Column = 8 And Target.OFFSET(0, -6).Value = "variable" Then 
                CreateColourPopUp Target
            End If
        Else
            DeleteAllTagPopUps Target
            DeleteAllColourPopUps Target
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This line `If Target.Column = 7 And Target.OFFSET(0, -5).Value = "variable"` (the 4th) is missing a `Then`

Comment: @VincentG I have just updated the question to clarify. The missing `THEN` was my mistake when pasting here, but is in my actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the missing `Then` spotted by @Vincent G, your procedure sports faulty logic. Because the second test runs irrespective of the result of the first, the *TagPopUp* created as a result of the first test can be deleted as a result of the second.

If this is intentional it isn't good or sensible practice. Instead, your code appears as if it was intentionally made complicated. Look at the ranges `ColourArea(ActiveSheet)` and `TagArea(ActiveSheet)`. The *ActiveSheet* in question doubtlessly is the object assigned to the `Sh` variable. It isn't good practice to refer to the same object by different names.

The two ranges are either overlapping or single-column. In either case the two `Intersect` tests should be nested, followed by a `Select` statement, like *If Target is within the range Then Select different processes for column 7, column 8 and Else".

`Target.Offset(0, -6)`, relating to column 8, and `Target.Offset(0, -5)`, relating to column 7 would appear to both specify `Sh.Cells(Target.Row, 2)`. Why hide this fact so artfully? In fact, it is a key component of your procedure's logic and "7 - 5" isn't any less hard-coded than "2". By paying due respect to this fact you might end up with a procedure like the one below.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    With Target
        If .Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
            If Not Intersect(Target, ColourArea(Sh)) Is Nothing Then
                If Sh.Cells(.Row, 2).Value = "variable" Then
                    Select Case .Column
                        Case 7
                            CreateTagPopUp Target
                        Case 8
                            CreateColourPopUp Target
                    End Select
                Else
                    DeleteAllTagPopUps Target
                    DeleteAllColourPopUps Target
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This procedure isn't tested. However, the intention isn't to provide code that you can copy, paste and use happily ever after. Rather, I want to show how to structure code to be transparent so as to avoid the traps built into the procedure you published that lead to your having to ask a question at all. The above one you can fix yourself. Please do so if it needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing and `End If`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, ColourArea(ActiveSheet)) Is Nothing Then 
        If Target.Column = 8 And Target.Offset(0, -6).Value = "Variable" Then
            CreateColourPopUp Target
        End If
    Else 
        DeleteAllPopUps Target
    End If ' <---- add an End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh I accidentally deleted that `THEN` while pasting the code here. My actual code has it but still not working as it should. I will edit the question to show the original code that works, and what I've added that makes it not work.